# How can I force format read only usb drive in OSx El Capitan?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb

I have a crashed laptop and used the [following method](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) to make a bootable usb drive (32 GB).

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso

diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN

sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
```

It did work and made a read only usb that acted as if it were a CD. I would like to now undo that (in OSx) but disk utility doesn't seem to be able to. When I click "Erase" it simply fails with

```
"Erase process has failed"
```

And details reveal

```
Name invalid.
Operation failed...
```

Is there a way I can force format this USB drive (to either FAT 32 or OSX Extended) in OSx El Capitan?

Comment: What file system are you trying to format it to? Not UDRW again?

Comment: I'm not too fussed tbh. I just want it to be a blank FAT32 or OS x Extended (Journalled).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved.

```
sudo diskutil unmountdisk force disk2

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2 bs=1024 count=1024
```

Comment: +1 it resolved my problem of a read-only usb drive.

Comment: I got this - dd: /dev/disk2: Permission denied

Comment: Among all answers this was the only one that really worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My experience: playing around with SD Cards for my Raspberry Pi 3 somehow one of them got read only on a Mac. I realized that the card was formatted MBR and OS X doesn't read/write MBR but GPT.
Solution:

I used Gparted (Linux)

1. Device>Create Partition Table> Select new partition table type>GPT
2. Partition>New>File system>fat32
3. Partition>Format to>fat32

Done